# Username + password = one word

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word in English, which describes combination of username and password?

Let's say, I want to say **Enter your "this_word"**, meaning **Enter your username and password**.

**EDIT**:

I'll exlpain, why I need this (because I see that it's being asked), though I see some answers, which fit my requirements. I'm a software developer (freelancer) and I'm creating a Desktop application, where login/password pair is present. But after releasing the first version of application I got the feedback, that It isn't clear for 'stupid' (no offense, just expression) users what they have to enter. So before it was like:

```
|username (placeholder)|
|password (placeholder)|
```

and after the feedback I want to change it to something like

```
Enter your Google 'word'
|username (placeholder)|
|password (placeholder)|
```

so, that's it.

Comment: Though there are some options, I wouldn't recommend this from a user experience point of view.

Comment: I think context is important. Are you writing instructions that will live apart from an actual website or is this to accompany an actual login form? If it's the latter, I would very much advise against this (even if this isn't ux.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Did you label your text boxes properly (i.e. next to the box), or did you just use a placeholder?

Comment: @CodesInChaos no but it's good idea.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with "Enter your username and password." It tells the user exactly what they're supposed to do. If you write "Enter your [something else]", then, especially given that you can't figure out what word to use, it's very likely that your users (especially the stupid ones) will say, "Enter my _what_?"

Comment: The solution to the feedback isn't to make things *more* obscure by using a term that you've had to ask ELU for. :-) To solution is to more *clear* by being explicit about what the user should enter.

Comment: If you'd asked this on the UX site, I'd post an answer saying you'd be better off simply stating the *action* to be taken, in plain English, which is logging in to Google. For example, "Log in to your Google account".

Comment: From an outsiders perspective, this seems like a case of asking the wrong question. Based on the user feedback, the quest I'd ask is not, "what's one word to communicate username and password?" but, "how can I effectively communicate what needs to be done?"

Comment: This should probably be on the UX site.

Comment: From a technical perspective, within HTTP, an answer to this question would be "basic auth": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication
I wouldn't suggest suggest using it with users though..

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Consider **"Enter your login credentials"**.

> [**Credentials**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/credentials)
>
> 1. Usually, credentials. evidence of authority, status, rights, entitlement to privileges, or the like, usually in written form:
>    *"Only those with the proper credentials are admitted."*
> 2. Anything that provides the basis for confidence, belief, credit, etc.

Comment: But if you are using this on a real website, this may leave the user wondering whether they need to enter their username or their email address, before their password. For a smoother [user experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), it may be better to inform the user precisely what they need to do, rather than leave them guessing.

Comment: @joeytwiddle - I didn't make it up.  It's what I've seen on real websites.  I agree in principle, though: as a breed, *users* are right up there with turkeys and sheep as some of the dumbest creatures on the farm. :-0

Comment: This is the correct term I've used it on many websites. Labels next to each input or placeholder text should provide the specific requirements but "enter your credentials" is a good section header.

Comment: "Credentials" is [consistently used by developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) to refer to the combination of username/password but also to other mechanisms to identify a user (eg private certificate)

Comment: @joeytwiddle: Which is why we have labels for input fields.

Comment: Given the edit to the question, I would say this is the best answer. "Credentials" paired with text boxes labeled as "username" and "password" I think this works. Though if it were me I'd just go with "username and password"

Comment: Me too: "Credentials" is *the* single word for "username and password" (and thus you might have a variable in your source code named `credentials` instead of the cumbersome `username_and_password`). However, in a user interface, you would never use the obscure and legalistic word "credentials" when you could just as easily write out "username and password". (Also, if by "username" you mean "email address", you should write out "email address"! That will help the people, myself included, who never remember whether they need to log in as `john.doe@gmail.com` or just `john.doe`.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone it's quite common for the user to see "credentials" in the Linux world.  It might not fit the naive-user part of the question though.

Comment: A suitably hardcore user might reasonably ask, "Which credentials: my public key? Kerberos authentication? My login name and password? The API key for this particular service?"  I think the average desktop-application user would be more likely to ask "What are *credentials*?" ;)

Comment: @Quuxplusone I think you're imagining issues. Most people will be able to figure it out from context clues - those who don't know what "credentials" means are likely to skip right over the header and look at the fields, which should be individually labeled *anyway*. Though to be honest, the most logical header is probably simply "Login".

Comment: We have some of the absolute dumbest users ever invented, yet they have no trouble understanding "please enter your login credentials". (True story: I once had a woman rail at me that a form was broken because when she clicked the "cancel changes" button, her changes weren't saved. And then there was the guy who didn't understand why a form wouldn't accept "2/31/2015" as a valid date.)

Answer (score 19):

If you really want one word:

- Enter your authentication.
- Enter your credentials.
- Enter your Information.

If you're trying for a single word, "authentication" is likely to be the best, but it's going to depend on the audience.

Comment: authentication is what you add to confirm who you are so would be just the password not the username

Comment: Credentials is correct. Authentication is a process not an object.

Comment: I agree, but credentials hints to users that they should pass over their resume or diploma, authentication works better in my experience, though not technically 100% correct. That being said, the best answer is to not ask for either and instead ask explicitly for what you need. In the edited questions I normally have to enter my MFA code.

Comment: @coteyr regardless, "authentication" is never the right word here. "credentials" is by far the most common.

Answer (score 16):

I wouldn't try to do it as a single word. If you don't want to have labels before each field, I'd write:

```
Enter your Google username and password
[username]
[password]
```

Maybe this question would be better posted at ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Agreed.  The person's motivation for asking this may not be limited to mastery of the English language.  [User Experience (Stack Exchange)](http://ux.stackexchange.com) (as Barmar suggested) would be appropriate, as would [Information Security (Stack Exchange)](http://security.stackexchange.com), and either of those might be a better place for discussing the experience that end users have with security, while keeping this [English (Stack Exchange)](http://english.stackexchange.com) area focused only on what words mean or how they are used.

Answer (score 11):

Particularly if the authentication method may be anything other than username and password (such as including a one-time code), I recommend:

**Enter your `XXX` login information**

(where `XXX` may be Google, Facebook, etc)

Answer (score 2):

*Enter your **login details/login data***

> [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=login+data%2Clogin+details&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clogin%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clogin%20details%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Given the edits, you may need to be more flexible in what your asking for. When logging in via google I (for example) have to enter one of four pieces of information.

- Username, password, and MFA token
- Username and single application password
- password and authorization for an app to read my profile (or parts there of)
- Just the authorization for an app to read my profile (or parts of it)

Because you need different amounts of information depending on how the user's google account is setup, you need a phrase that covers all possibilities.

---

- **Login and authorize** app name:
- **Grant access** to app name:
- **Authenticate** with Google:
- **Login** using Google:
- Login using Google authentication:
- Login using Google credentials:

---

Answer (score 1):

People who are information security professionals discuss these concepts a lot.  And, therefore, they've really been motivated to come up with a short phrase.  The most common term is "credentials".

Unfortunately, a lot of end users don't seem to be very familiar with using that word in that way, but that is the word that is most commonly used.

"login credentials" is probably more clear for end users.

Since you're seeking to use the phrase, "Enter your Google '*(something)*'", I would suggest:

`Enter your Google account information:`

That should be clear when people  also see the field descriptions of "username" and "password".  That doesn't fulfill the question you're asking (a single word-- "credentials" is the best word for summarizing that detail), but using multiple words will do a better job at fulfilling purpose that you are seeking to accomplish.  Things will be more clear for people.

Comment: "authentication" could also be used instead of "credentials".  I didn't put that in my answer, though, because it is in coteyr's answer.